# Problems with hector_slam/ Tutorial

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the tutorial with hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch with Hydro.  This is the error that I keep getting:

```
leaf@leaf:~$ roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch
... logging to /home/leaf/.ros/log/14c6a7e2-6008-11e5-9b56-5cd99897b32a/roslaunch-leaf-2187.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://leaf.local:41228/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /hector_geotiff_node/draw_background_checkerboard
 * /hector_geotiff_node/draw_free_space_grid
 * /hector_geotiff_node/geotiff_save_period
 * /hector_geotiff_node/map_file_base_name
 * /hector_geotiff_node/map_file_path
 * /hector_geotiff_node/plugins
 * /hector_mapping/advertise_map_service
 * /hector_mapping/base_frame
 * /hector_mapping/laser_z_max_value
 * /hector_mapping/laser_z_min_value
 * /hector_mapping/map_frame
 * /hector_mapping/map_multi_res_levels
 * /hector_mapping/map_resolution
 * /hector_mapping/map_size
 * /hector_mapping/map_start_x
 * /hector_mapping/map_start_y
 * /hector_mapping/map_update_angle_thresh
 * /hector_mapping/map_update_distance_thresh
 * /hector_mapping/odom_frame
 * /hector_mapping/pub_map_odom_transform
 * /hector_mapping/scan_subscriber_queue_size
 * /hector_mapping/scan_topic
 * /hector_mapping/tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name
 * /hector_mapping/update_factor_free
 * /hector_mapping/update_factor_occupied
 * /hector_mapping/use_tf_pose_start_estimate
 * /hector_mapping/use_tf_scan_transformation
 * /hector_trajectory_server/source_frame_name
 * /hector_trajectory_server/target_frame_name
 * /hector_trajectory_server/trajectory_publish_rate
 * /hector_trajectory_server/trajectory_update_rate
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    hector_geotiff_node (hector_geotiff/geotiff_node)
    hector_mapping (hector_mapping/hector_mapping)
    hector_trajectory_server (hector_trajectory_server/hector_trajectory_server)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rviz-1]: started with pid [2205]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hector_mapping/hector_mapping]: can't locate node [hector_mapping] in package [hector_mapping]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hector_trajectory_server/hector_trajectory_server]: can't locate node [hector_trajectory_server] in package [hector_trajectory_server]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hector_geotiff/geotiff_node]: can't locate node [geotiff_node] in package [hector_geotiff]
```

Any help would be very appreciated.  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217932/problems-with-hector_slam/-tutorial/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2015-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like you either did not build the packages or your ROS workspace setup is broken and the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is not set correctly. There are [many similar questions on ROS Answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=can%27t%20locate%20node%20ros%20answers%20ROS_PACKAGE_PATH) you might want to look at.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0